# Undefined offset error when running SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Each time I run the the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_accident WHERE progress = 'on hire' AND progress = 'vd'
```

But it returns an error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\newclaim\cases.php on line 139
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\newclaim\cases.php on line 139

Alternatively when I run:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_accident WHERE progress = 'on hire';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_accident WHERE progress = 'vd';
```

There is no problem. What am I doing wrong? The code at line 138-140 reads:

```
<td><?php $caseOpen = explode("/", $row_cases['caseOpen']); 
  $caseOpen = $caseOpen[2].'/'.$caseOpen[1].'/'.$caseOpen[0]; 
  echo $caseOpen;?></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently always getting 0 rows returned from your select.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_accident WHERE progress in ('on hire', 'vd')
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_accident WHERE progress='on hire' OR progress='vd'
```

You used `AND` instead of `OR` in your query. Using `AND` will never return any result because `progress` can't be `vd` and `on hire` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your sql. You are using progress in where clause more than on time using AND. YOu can use OR instead of AND